Multiple SNS Subscriptions To Same Endpoint with Different Subscription Filter Policies
I am working on a project where I manage JSON schemas that contain metadata used for notification emails. My goal is to dynamically create AWS SNS Subscriptions and configure their Subscription Policy Filters using the metadata provided in these schemas.
Initially, I planned to have a 1:1 relationship between schemas and SNS subscriptions, but I’ve encountered a challenge. Multiple schemas might share the same email recipient. This creates a conflict since SNS subscriptions are unique to an email per topic.
Challenges:

Managing filter policies to ensure that the correct filters apply to the recipient without overwriting or conflicting with others.

I tried creating multiple SNS Subscriptions with the same Endpoint & Protocol, with differing Subscription Policy Filters, however i am presented with:
An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation:
Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Subscription already exists with different attributes

I’ve considered the following workflow to manage this limitation:

Parse all JSON schemas to get a unique list of emails and create one SNS subscription per email for the topic.

Iterate over the schemas again to compile a merged filter policy for each subscription.


Questions:

Are there any other approaches that might make more sense for handling this use case?

What’s the least complex and most manageable solution for applying distinct filter policies to the same recipient across multiple schemas?


